# Slider Scale control dynamically not updating values

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I created a slider scale control by editing slider template & adding a class which inherits Slider Base Class in Win RT.
It will display scale values  dynamically create division with respect to it's the Maximum & Minimum value of slider .
for example : if Minimum value is 0 & maximum value is 100 ;it will display 0,100,200,300 etc..
The  method is called from  OnApplyTemplate override

```
 public sealed class ScaleControl : Slider
{      
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        SetScaleValues(this.Minimum, this.Maximum);
    }   

 private void SetScaleValues(double MinValue, double MaxValue)
    {
     //logic here
}
```

}

If we give Max & Min in XAML it will work fine.
My problem is that "it is not updating divisions when we give Slider Max & Min dynamically by code behind".
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using data binding in your XAML to set these values? Please paste your XAML slider tag and I can help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [PropertyChangeEventSource](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0657c67a93d5#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/PropertyChangeEventSource.cs) control from the WinRT XAML Toolkit. You can check a sample use in the [NumericUpDown](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0657c67a93d5#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/NumericUpDown.cs) control.

Basically you could do something like

```
var pcc =
    new PropertyChangeEventSource<double>(this, "Minimum");
pcc.ValueChanged += OnMinimumChanged;

private void OnMinimumCHanged(object source, double minimum) {}
```